# Multiple issues with User Registration from frontend

Tags: registration, user-groups

I am not able to get User Registration to work properly using a frontend form from the Craft Docs (https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/user-registration-form).

Here are the particulars:

Craft Pro Version = 2.6.2791

Users > Settings has the ‘verify email addresses’ and ‘allow public registration’ boxes checked, and a default User group selected

I specified a redirect in craft > config > general to 'activateAccountSuccessPath' => 'registration-success',

The form submits and the user is created, but no verification email is sent and the user is not assigned to the group I selected in User Settings. If I manually send a verification email, following the link causes the user to be verified, but still not added to any Group. Further, the user is redirected to http://sitename/dashboard, despite having a redirect set in the Config > General file.

I tried this on two different Craft sites, each on different hosts (one of which is Arcustech) and both of which are running the latest Craft release (2.6.2791).

Answer (score 1):

> The form submits and the user is created, but no verification email is sent and the user is not assigned to the group I selected in User Settings.

That sounds like there is a validation error is happening in your form on the UserModel.  Perhaps on a required custom field. You didn't share your form, but is it checking for errors?

> If I manually send a verification email, following the link causes the user to be verified, but still not added to any Group.

Make sure you're not running any plugins that might be interfering listening to the `onSaveUser` event.

> Further, the user is redirected to http://sitename/dashboard, despite having a redirect set in the Config > General file.

That's a bug that's been fixed for the next (post [2.6.2791](https://craftcms.com/changelog#build2791)) release.

Comment: Good call, Brad! The Charge plugin from Squarebit is the culprit - after disabling it everything works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing specific in Charge that touches any of the user events, and I can't replicate this with any clean install. @RoiAgneta - are you running anything custom on top of Charge that's adding extra user handling?

Comment: For future reference to anyone running across this, it wasn't anything specific to Charge causing it. Actual problem looks like it was a more general server setup problem.

Comment: @JoelBradbury A likely story.

Comment: After hours of playing around with this, it turns out that Charge is not causing any issues. Still do not understand what is going on, will update when i get it sorted.